# Date Time Offset not working

Tags: c#

I am not very familiar with dealing with date time spans etc in C#

Please see my test below

I am giving it 2 dates

I then want to change the dates to be offset from the replay date

This works perfect for the first date

But my second date is not working I need it to be 13:05 but its 13:00

```
        var dates = new List<DateTime>()
        {
            Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 10:00"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 10:05")
        };

        var replayDate = Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 13:00");

        for (var index = 0; index < dates.Count; index++)
        {
            var date = dates[index];

            var time = replayDate.TimeOfDay - date.TimeOfDay;

            var newTime = date.Add(time);
            dates[index] = newTime;
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 13:00"), dates[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 13:05"), dates[1]);
```

Whats the best approach to do this?

Paul

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "offset"? Simply find out the difference?

Comment: Maybe offset is not the right term to use but basically I have a replay date so I want my dates to start at that date then carry on as shown in the expected results

Comment: `time` should be `replayDate.TimeOfDay - dates[0].TimeOfDay` - you want the offset to be the difference between your `replayDate` and the first date, this should therefore also be **outside (before) the loop**

Comment: Not sure why this was recommended for being closed.  Thanks for the help @rafalon and everyone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 10:00"),
    Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 10:05")
};

var replayDate = Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 13:00");
// process the offset once (before the loop) -- here it will be 3 hours
var offset = replayDate.TimeOfDay - dates[0].TimeOfDay;

for (var index = 0; index < dates.Count; index++)
{
    // shift all your dates by that offset
    dates[index] = dates[index].Add(offset);
}

Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 13:00"), dates[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime("29/06/2018 13:05"), dates[1]);
```

As per my comment:

`time` should be `replayDate.TimeOfDay - dates[0].TimeOfDay` - you want the offset to be the difference between your `replayDate` and the first date, this should therefore also be **outside (before) the loop**.

[Here](http://tpcg.io/dSdSfx) is a code snippet to demonstrate.
Note that I formatted the date strings as `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` because of the server's culture.